# Ruby, Telnet, read multiline response without timeout

Tags: ruby, json, telnet

I need some hints/help, how can I read multiline response into variable.
My current command results me multiline response but after that I get timeout.

Here's how my connection is setup:

```
connection = Net::Telnet.new('Host' => host,'Port' => 4800, 'Telnetmode' => false, 'Timeout' => 1)
```

Here's my request and how I save it:

```
puts "Weather request\n"
connection.cmd("{weather}"){ |c| print c }
parsed = JSON.parse(str)
puts "#{parsed}\n\n"
```

And here's the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/telnet.rb:558:in `waitfor': timed out while waiting for more data (Timeout::Error)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/telnet.rb:695:in `cmd'
    from ruby_check.rb:37:in `<main>'
```

My response is multiple JSON lines, like this:

```
{"City":"Tallinn", "Degrees":"23"}
{"City":"Berlin", "Degrees":"23"}
{"City":"Helsinki", "Degrees":"23"}
{"City":"Stockholm", "Degrees":"23"}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I am waiting for result as I described above, "My response is multiple JSON lines" and continue to sending next command without timeout. Currently my script wont continue to next command.

Comment: The assignment `connection = Net::Telnet(... 'Promp'` appears to be truncated. Maybe you wnat to  correct that.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why the timeout?

The [`Net::Telnet` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html) says:

> For some protocols, it will be possible to specify the Prompt option once when you create the Telnet object and use cmd() calls; for others, you will have to specify the response sequence to look for as the Match option to every cmd() call, or call puts() and waitfor() directly; for yet others, you will have to use sysread() instead of waitfor() and parse server responses yourself.

This makes more sense when combined with the [`Net::Telnet#cmd` method's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#method-i-cmd), which says that the method:

> sends a string to the host, and reads in all received data until is sees the prompt or other matched sequence.

You're not specifying a custom `Prompt` or `Match` option, so `#cmd` is waiting for something from the server that matches the default `Net::Telnet` prompt (`/[$%#>] \z/n`) to indicate the end of the message.
If the message doesn't end with that kind of prompt, then it'll be waiting forever.

### Possible solutions

#### Match the server's prompt

If the server does send some kind of prompt to indicate it's finished sending data and you should type the next command, you can pass a regular expression that matches it to the `Net::Telnet` initialiser. For example, if the server prompted you with `command:`, you could use:

```
connection = Net::Telnet.new(
  "Prompt" => /command: \z/,
  # …
)
```

#### Match the end of the response

If there's no prompt, but the response you're waiting for ends with a specific character sequence, you could explicitly specify the `Match` option when you call `#cmd`. For example, if your response was a single JSON array it would end with `]`, so you might be able to use this:

```
connection.cmd("String" => "{weather}", "Match" => "]") { |c| print c }
```

#### Give up on `Net::Telnet` and use a `TCPSocket`

If there's no prompt and no known ending, you could try to use the `Net::Telnet` object's underlying [`TCPSocket`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) to read the data without using `#cmd`:

```
connection.puts("{weather}")
connection.sock.readline
```

At this point, there might not be much benefit to using `Net::Telnet` over a plain `TCPSocket`.

Comment: Thank you for this very comprohensive answer! Ill try to use TCPSocket instead of telnet:)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the timeout to one second and do not specify what `str` is. You can try increasing the timeout value or even setting it to [false](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#new-method). Believieng it is the result from `.cmd`, try this:

```
connection = Net::Telnet.new(
  "Host" => host, "Port" => 4800, 
  "Telnetmode" => false, "Timeout" => false)

puts "Weather request...\n"

str = connection.cmd("{weather}"){ |c| print c }
parsed = JSON.parse(str)

puts "#{parsed}\n\n"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it wait then eternally for next responces?

Comment: The Doc states "You can disable the timeout by setting this value to false. In this case, the connect attempt will eventually timeout on the underlying connect(2) socket call with an Errno::ETIMEDOUT error (but generally only after a few minutes), but other attempts to read data from the host *will hand indefinitely* if no data is forthcoming." So in the first step I would simply try to increase your timeout value to 5 or 10 seconds.

Comment: I've tried with timeout 10 and 50 seconds but the result is same. It just keeps waiting next responses until timeout is reached.